# Comparing Sets with 'comm'

Tags: bash, shell-script, comm

Trying to get a list of available IP addresses based off all usable IPs in a range when compared to a device's ARP table.

Basing what I'm doing with `comm` on this discussion: [Intersection of two arrays in BASH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104837/intersection-of-two-arrays-in-bash)

Creating ranges of IPs to compare against - e..g 192.168.20.0/23

```
RANGE1=(192.168.20.{2..255})
RANGE2=(192.168.21.{0..254})
RANGE=("${RANGE1[@]}" "${RANGE2[@]}")
printf '%s\n' "${RANGE[@]}" | LC_ALL=C sort > "${IPSETS_DIR}/<city-alias>_set.txt"
```

$1 is an IP of a network device. OID is basically a device's ARP table. GREP_SEARCH example: "192.168.20|192.168.30|192.168.55"

```
$(which snmpbulkwalk) -v2c -c <community-string> "${1}" .1.3.6.1.2.1.4.35.1.4 > "${RESULTS_FILE}"
STRIPPED_RESULTS=( $(cut -d\" -f2 "${RESULTS_FILE}" | egrep -w "(^|\s)${GREP_SEARCH}") )
printf "%s\n" "${STRIPPED_RESULTS[@]}" | LC_ALL=C sort > "${STRIPPED_FILE}"
```

The walk returns results such as:
`IP-MIB::ipNetToPhysicalPhysAddress.118161416.ipv4."X.X.X.X" = STRING: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`

I then compare using the below. $1 is city-alias.

```
$(which comm) -13 "${STRIPPED_FILE}" "${IPSETS_DIR}/${1}_set.txt" > "${DIR}/${1}_stored_results.txt"
```

This MOSTLY works, but I'm still getting IPs that are in use. Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Related [Linux tools to treat files as sets and perform set operations on them](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/11343)

Comment: "Set Complement" - "comm -23 <(sort set1) <(sort set2)" - "# outputs elements in set1 that are not in set2" -- That's it. Thanks for the link! Also, my GREP_SEARCH wasn't completely correct, so that was throwing me off.

Comment: `$(which comm)` is a really weird statement. Why not juse `comm`? (Likewise elsewhere; you really don't need `which` like this - just use the command.)

Comment: Yeah, definitely better ways to handle that. Everyone that will be using what I'm writing, besides myself, will be on WSL or Mac, so trying to make sure it'll work everywhere.

Comment: which(1) is already searching inside the `PATH`, so there is no reason to use it. If `comm` fails, so will `$(which comm)`. Besides, there is only a handful of locations that command could normally be installed, most likely /usr/bin.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just going to read up on POSIX, try and conform it to that.

Answer (score 0):

Stéphane's link gave me my answer.

> Set Complement
> $ comm -23 <(sort set1) <(sort set2)
> # outputs elements in set1 that are not in set2